# Evitar sobrecargado de fragments usando tabs, tengo tres cronometros y quiero que sean independientes uno del otro, android studio

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Tengo tres cronómetros ubicados en fragments y estos a su vez en tab, necesito que cada cronometro sea independiente uno del otro, para evitar el sobrecargado de fragments, el cual me impide llevar un control de las personas, porque los tres se manejan por el primero que se inicie Consulte y encontré que con `Hide()` y `Show()` se podría dar respuesta a lo que buscando, pero la verdad no he podido implementarlo, ya que no se exactamente donde ubicar el código que aparece en internet.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabItem tab1,tab2,tab3;
public PageAdapter pagerAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    tabLayout=findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
    viewPager=findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    tab1=(TabItem)findViewById(R.id.Tab1);
    tab2=(TabItem)findViewById(R.id.Tab2);
    tab3=(TabItem)findViewById(R.id.Tab3);

    pagerAdapter = new PageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), 
   tabLayout.getTabCount());

    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

            if (tab.getPosition() == 0){

                pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else if (tab.getPosition() == 1){

                pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else if (tab.getPosition() == 2){

                pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new 
    TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));




}
```

}

```
  public class PageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

  private int numoftabs;


 public PageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int numOfTabs) {
     super(fm);
    this.numoftabs = numOfTabs;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {



    switch (position){

        case 0:
            return new tab1();
        case 1:
            return new tab2();
        case 2:
            return new tab3();

            default:
                return null;


    }



}




@Override
public int getCount() {
    return numoftabs;
}

@Override
public int getItemPosition(@NonNull Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}
```

}

```
public class tab1 extends Fragment {
Chronometer crono;
Button inicio,parar;


public tab1() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab1, container, false);

    crono=v.findViewById(R.id.cronouno);
    inicio=v.findViewById(R.id.btniniciouno);
    parar=v.findViewById(R.id.btnpararuno);

    inicio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            crono.start();
        }
    });

    parar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            crono.stop();
        }
    });
    return v;



}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Mira intenta lo siguiente en vez de crear una nueva instancia cada vez que llamas al fragment crea un singleton te explico como deberias hacer

en la clase de los fragments ejemplo la clase que llamastes "tab1" crea el siguiente metodo

```
private static tab1 fragTab1;
public static tab1 newInstance(){
    if(fragTab1==null){
        fragTab1 = new tab1();
    }

    return fragTab1;
}
```

entonces en la clase del adapter vas a llamar a todos los fragments de la siguiente manera

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position){

        case 0:
            return tab1.newInstance();
        case 1:
            return tab2.newInstance();
        case 2:
            return tab3.newInstance();

            default:
                return null;
    }
}
```

ok te explico lo que logras con eso basicamente evitas que cada vez que te muevas entre tabs cree una nueva instancia del fragment con lo cual se queda con el estado en el que estaba.

Otra cosita que noto en tu codigo porfavor evita colocar la primera letra del nombre de las clase en minuscula eso es una mala practica la clase que llamastes "tab1" deberia ser "Tab1" con la T en mayuscula.